# Swift iOS How to display an alert message from the handler of another alert message

Tags: ios, swift, handler, alert, message

I'm trying to implement a forgot password feature in my app so users can enter their email in and have it reset in the database and have the new generated password emailed to them.

I believe my code should work once I fix a few minor issues but the main hurdle I'm having is how to display an alert message from the handler of another alert message.

Any idea how to do it? Either the alert message doesn't show up at all or the first one doesn't close at all.

Here is my attempt at it:

```
    //This function will send a password reset email
func emailPassword(alertAction: UIAlertAction!) -> Void {
    let textField = reset_alert.textFields![0] as UITextField

    if(!textField.text!.isEmpty){

        if(textField != "mik"){
            let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
            let forgotten_email = textField.text
            query.whereKey("email", equalTo: forgotten_email!)
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
                (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                //NO ERROR//
                if(error == nil){
                    //email in db generate random password
                    let letters : NSString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"

                    let randomString : NSMutableString = NSMutableString(capacity: 12)
                    var users_name = ""

                    for _ in 0...10{
                        let length = UInt32 (letters.length)
                        let rand = arc4random_uniform(length)
                        randomString.appendFormat("%C", letters.characterAtIndex(Int(rand)))
                    }

                    //set new password for user
                    if let objects = objects {
                        for object in objects {
                            object["_hashed_password"] = randomString
                            users_name = object["name"] as! String

                            //send password to email
                            self.mailgun.sendMessageTo("\(users_name) <\(textField)>", from: "")

                            self.displayAlert("SUCCESS", msg: "Check your email for your new password")
                            self.reset_alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        self.reset_alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                        self.displayAlert("ERROR", msg: "Email not registered to an account")

                    }
                }

                    //ERROR//
                else{
                    self.reset_alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                    self.displayAlert("ERROR", msg: "Email not registered to an account")                    }
            } //end if textfield not admin email

            self.presentViewController(reset_alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }//end of if textfield is empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension:

```
typealias AlertActionBlock = (UIAlertAction) -> Void
extension UIViewController {
    func flash(title title:String?, message:String?, cancelTitle:String?, actions:UIAlertAction?...) {
        let b = {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let cancelBlock:AlertActionBlock = {(action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in }
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: cancelTitle, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: cancelBlock)
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
            for action in actions {if let action = action {alertController.addAction(action)}}
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        if NSThread.isMainThread() {
            b()
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), b)
        }
    }
}
```

That should let you call that function from background threads or the main thread just call that function and fill in the variables

EDIT (I didn't realize you need a textfield) so try this:

```
func flash(title title:String?, message:String?, textFieldConfigurator:(UITextField -> Void)? = nil, cancelTitle:String?, actions:UIAlertAction?...) {
        let b = { () -> Void in
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            if let textFieldConfigurator = textFieldConfigurator {alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(textFieldConfigurator)}
            let cancelBlock:AlertActionBlock = {(action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in }
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: cancelTitle, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: cancelBlock)
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
            for action in actions {if let action = action {alertController.addAction(action)}}
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        if NSThread.isMainThread() {
            b()
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), b)
        }
    }
```

If you need multiple text fields make it an array and iterate through it. Let me know how it goes!